# Blank window when lanching about dialogue twice?

Tags: python, linux, gtk, gnome, pygobject

I have an application design done, without any useful stuff happening, but I have two windows. One is the main window, and one is the about dialogue. They are all on one .ui file from Glade.

When I open the About dialogue using Help>About (in my program), everything works. Closing it and opening it again using the same method results in a blank window.

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

class window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()

        self.builder.add_from_file("./personalinfo.ui")

        self.mainWindow = self.builder.get_object("mainWindow")

        self.mainWindow.connect("destroy", self.on_mainWindow_destroy)

        self.mainWindow.set_title("Persona")

        self.mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxCancel = self.builder.get_object("mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxCancel")

        self.mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxCancel.connect("clicked", self.on_mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxCancel_clicked)

        self.mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK = self.builder.get_object("mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK")

        self.mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK.connect("clicked", self.on_mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK_clicked)

        self.mainWindowMainBoxGenderBoxCombo  = self.builder.get_object("mainWindowMainBoxGenderBoxCombo")

        self.mainWindowMainBoxGenderBoxCombo.set_active(0)

        self.mainWindowMainBoxMenuFileMenuQuit = self.builder.get_object("mainWindowMainBoxMenuFileMenuQuit")

        self.mainWindowMainBoxMenuFileMenuQuit.connect("activate", self.on_mainWindowMainBoxMenuFileMenuQuit_activate)

        self.mainWindowMainBoxMenuHelpMenuAbout = self.builder.get_object("mainWindowMainBoxMenuHelpMenuAbout")

        self.mainWindowMainBoxMenuHelpMenuAbout.connect("activate", self.on_mainWindowMainBoxMenuHelpMenuAbout_activate)

        self.mainWindow.show_all()

    def on_mainWindow_destroy(self, widget):
        print("destroy: 'mainWindow'")

        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxCancel_clicked(self, widget):
        print("clicked: 'mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxCancel'")

        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK_clicked(self, widget):
        print("clicked: 'mainWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK'")

        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_mainWindowMainBoxMenuFileMenuQuit_activate(self, widget):
        print("activate: 'mainWindowMainBoxMenuFileMenuQuit'")

        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_mainWindowMainBoxMenuHelpMenuAbout_activate(self, widget):
        print("activate: 'mainWindowMainBoxMenuHelpMenuAbout'")

        self.aboutWindow = self.builder.get_object("aboutWindow")

        self.aboutWindow.set_title("About Persona")

        self.aboutWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK = self.builder.get_object("aboutWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK")

        self.aboutWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK.connect("clicked", self.on_aboutWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK_clicked)

        self.aboutWindow.show_all()

    def on_aboutWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK_clicked(self, widget):
        print("clicked: 'aboutWindowMainBoxButtonBoxOK'")

        self.aboutWindow.destroy()

w = window()

Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The About window isn't created each time you call `self.aboutWindow = self.builder.get_object("aboutWindow")` it is created once when you load the UI file. So when you call `self.aboutWindow.destroy()` it destroys it forever, and the next time you try to display the window it no longer exists.

Instead of destroying the window, you probably want to hide it instead `self.aboutWindow.hide()`

Comment: Thanks, I thought it got a new instance of aboutWindow every time I assigned it to self.aboutWindow